# Is it possible to close out a github issue, and associate it to a commit?

Tags: git, github

I think it would be useful to be able to look at historical issues, and be able to view the commit(s) that closed out the issue.

Is this currently possible?

Comment: You should read this: https://guides.github.com/features/issues/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Simply reference the issue number from anywhere in the commit message using `#xxx`.

You can also [close issues](https://help.github.com/articles/closing-issues-via-commit-messages/) this way.